# sscanf() not properly parsing the input line

Tags: c, string, string-parsing, scanf

I'm writing a method to parse a string in a specific format, `"55555;fhihehj;"`

I have used `sscanf` in the past to do something similar, so I thought why not.

Here is my current code.

```
char toBreak[] = "55555;fjfjfhhj;";  
char* strNum = malloc(256); //256 * sizeof(char) = 256  
char* name = malloc(256);  
if (sscanf(toBreak, "%[^;];%[^;];", strNum, name)!=2)   
     return -1;
printf("%s, %s\n", strNum, name);
```

For some reason, it isn't parsing the string correctly and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your compilable code and making it into an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) gives us:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char toBreak[] = "55555;fjfjfhhj;";
    char *strNum = malloc(256);
    char *name = malloc(256);
    if (sscanf(toBreak, "%255[^;];%255[^;];", strNum, name) != 2)
        return -1;
    printf("%s, %s\n", strNum, name);
    return 0;
}
```

I added the `255` to prevent buffer overflows in the general case where the input is not a constant in the program.  Here, of course, the 256 byte allocations are very much larger than necessary, and overflow is not a problem.  Note the 'off-by-one' on the length; the length in the format does not include the null byte, but there must be space for the null byte.

When compiled and run on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks with GCC 4.8.2, that gives:

```
55555, fjfjfhhj
```

What platform are you running on — o/s and compiler?  What do you get with the code I show?

Comment: Using your code, it properly works. I'm honestly not sure what was going weird, but I appreciate it. By the way, CentOS with gcc 4.4.7 is my platform.